# codename one. IOS intercepting URLs issue.

Tags: android, ios, url, codenameone

I want my app to be able to intercept urls when opened in an external application. I managed to get it working on android using the android.xintent_filter build hint with the url scheme "http". However it does not work on ios. I added this build hint exactly as instructed here: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/intercepting-urls-on-ios-android.html ...

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>     <array>         <dict>              
<key>CFBundleURLName</key>               
<string>www.mibrand.co.za</string>           
</dict>         <dict>             <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>               
<array>                 <string>http</string>             </array>             
</dict>     </array>
```

I even tried changing the url scheme to "myapp" because I read somewhere that ios does not allow apps to intercept http url schemes however it still didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

And on another note. Is what I read true about ios and http url schemes. Because when I try changing the url scheme in my android.xintent build hint to "myapp" android phones don't pick up the text as a link and therefore cannot open them so I am forced to use the http url scheme. But if that doesn't work for ios then I am in a bit of a problem. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Facebook integration [check this out](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_intercepting_url%27s_on_ios_android).

Specifically:

> However, that can conflict with the Facebook integration if you use
>   FacebookConnect which needs access to the schemes. To workaround it
>   you can use the build hint ios.urlScheme e.g.:

```
ios.urlScheme=<string>myapp</string>
```

Comment: adding the build hint ios.urlScheme worked. Is there a similar one for android. Because when I try a scheme on android other than http or https it doesn't register as a link

Comment: I don't think there is a similar thing there, I suggest posting a new question with the URL filter you used on Android

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible on iOS. Apps can be opened directly from other applications by using urls defined in the url schemes section of your info.plist, but it can't intercept http calls from other apps.

The only other option (if the url is linking to a website that you own) is to use Universal links, Universal links were introduced in iOS 9 and the documentation can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Bare in mind that Universal Links are only for websites that you own, and not for sites that you don't.

Comment: Yes but even when I change the scheme to "myapp" and click on the link it still doesn't work. There must also be something wrong with my permissions